# Create "regional user leagues" and "tag toppers"

Tags: feature-request

Given the current user base, most users will never see themselves high up on any of the all time lists. They may briefly find themselves on the last 30 days in the popular tags or the weekly/monthly/quarterly/yearly groups.

However, if you break down the lists by location, you might be in for a nice surprise (unless you live in Reading, Rouen, Forest of Dean or Willemstad). I know the location data isn't perfect but perhaps it will give people an incentive to put in cleaner data.

Also it doesn't have to be at location level. It could be done at the national or continent level, to remove advantages for small areas.

**TL;DR:** Add regional views to the "user leagues" and "tag top users."

#### Data.SE Queries:

- [Regional user rank](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1904/regional-user-rank)
- [Regional top 10 answerers by tag top 40 tags only](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1903/regional-top-10-answerers-by-tag-top-40-tags-only)

Comment: Isn't that "rewarding" people for living in the middle of nowhere rather than contributing at a superb level?  I'm not sure there's an actual benefit here.

Comment: Well in order to make the all-time list in C#, C++ (your favorite languages) you'd need at least an additional 3,000 upvotes (and 30,000 rep). However to get to #2 in Ontario you'd only need to score ~150 . Which is a bronze tag badge and not insignificant. Also I live in a city that's larger in population than the Top 5 SO users cities combined. The "middle of nowhere" people seem to dominate on SO

Comment: I rather suspect I could create sockpuppets and *repeatedly down-vote my main user*, while still managing to top a regional league. Really don't need more reminders that I'm not in California.

Comment: @Shog9 You're an interesting example. You have 40K rep. You're 20th on the on the all-time list for javascript. But as you mention you're #1 in several categories in Colorado. I think users especially new ones might enjoy that they can at least compete regionally. Even in large population areas. Of course by Matthew's reckoning you've barely contributed at a superb level.

Comment: @Conrad: yeah, but look at my activity - my participation has been pathetic this year. Which was my point: outside of maybe Denver, there's really no one to compete with here. This probably makes a lot more sense for the coastal areas... You should think about just doing up a page for this yourself, and then throw it up on Stack Apps.

Comment: @Shog9 That's a really good idea

Comment: It's also worth a mention that the top three new users in a time period are listed in the Reputation League sidebar.

Answer (score 4):

I ran your query and I'm last place in my region. Luckily, I'm also first place. I guess there aren't many SO users in [New London, CT](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=google+map+new+london+CT&ll=40.946714,-71.235352&spn=2.140901,5.377808&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-a&gl=us&t=m&z=8&vpsrc=6).

If I wanted to actually see how I rank by region, I'd have to change my location to something *less* specific like "CT", and if there weren't many results there, I'd try some neighboring regions like New York or Massachusetts.

So, In order to see how I rank in other regions, I'd have to put something fake in my user card, so the "incentive to put in cleaner data" is not there.

I kind of like the idea but I doubt it will actually work, and surely *some* people will start putting in fake locations so they can top an obscure list or "compete" in a region where they don't actually live.

Comment: Hah, I'm the #1 Python user in the _entire USA_ if you believe the query.

Answer (score 3):

> Given the current user base, most users will never see themselves high up on any of the all time lists.

The 30-day and shorter lists for both overall and tags are reachable for anyone, as are the all-time lists on many of the medium size to small tags if you specialize -- I only answer Python questions, and I'm pretty close to the all-time list, even though it's a fairly major tag.

Also, I've got "United States" as my location apparently, which means I'm the #1 Python user, #8 Django user, and #76 overall in the USA? If I'm a good example of how bad the location info is, these rankings won't do anything but make the few people who do look get an inflated sense of where they stand.

Regional Leagues seems so arbitrary, and unrelated to anything this site is about -- it is on the internet, after all.

Maybe something like student, professional, and enthusiast leagues would make more sense?

Comment: "Regional Leagues seems so arbitrary." You're right and I'm fine with that. I'd also be fine with a breakdown into the 3 groups you described. Or country, or age or first letter in user name, or some completely random distributions (Group A, B, C and D)