# How do I find my rank for a specific tag?

Tags: support, tags, reputation-leagues, rankings

I like watching my progress at the Stack Exchange leagues. But is it possible to find my rank for a specific tag (C# for example)?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can't find your rank, but you can find out how well you stack up against the highest in a tag.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/tags/<tagname>/topusers
```

It shows you at the bottom of the list (unless you're actually in the list) so you can compare to how much you need to improve to be on the list of top users.

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it gives you the basics. Of course if you're competing with someone you'd have to do a little more research or share information with them or something.

Comment: nearly there!!..http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mdx/topusers

Answer (score 46):

I think the best you can do is use this [data.SE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2097/tag-rankings) which currently puts you at 108 in the C# tag.

You can also use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/52750/tag-rankings-fun) if you just want a single tag or see who the other users are below is the first 109 users in c#

```
Rank    User Link                     Score
------- ----------------------------- -----
1       Jon Skeet                     56046
2       Marc Gravell                  29162
3       Eric Lippert                  17175
4       JaredPar                      11134
5       Darin Dimitrov                10685
6       Hans Passant                  10308
7       Reed Copsey                   10274
8       SLaks                          9997
9       Mehrdad Afshari                6891
10      Oded                           5466
11      Mark Byers                     5231
12      Henk Holterman                 5213
13      Joel Coehoorn                  4716
14      Andrew Hare                    4711
15      Jason                          4537
16      Guffa                          4306
17      dtb                            4272
18      LukeH                          3780
19      Fredrik Mörk                   3602
20      Justin Niessner                3582
21      tvanfosson                     3236
22      Adam Robinson                  3201
23      Thomas Levesque                3183
24      BrokenGlass                    3058
25      Lasse V. Karlsen               3002
26      John Saunders                  2872
27      marc_s                         2830
28      Konrad Rudolph                 2670
29      Mitch Wheat                    2489
30      LBushkin                       2441
31      Ani                            2338
32      Anthony Pegram                 2317
33      Noldorin                       2297
34      Brian Rasmussen                2256
35      Dan Tao                        2133
36      Rex M                          2102
37      ChrisF                         2037
37      leppie                         2037
39      BFree                          2012
40      Anton Gogolev                  1961
41      Mark Seemann                   1947
42      Matt Hamilton                  1930
43      Daniel Hilgarth                1925
44      Kent Boogaart                  1903
45      Greg Beech                     1896
46      Aaronaught                     1861
47      driis                          1795
48      CodeInChaos                    1732
49      Bala R                         1692
50      CMS                            1625
51      Kevin                          1595
52      0xA3                           1576
53      Mark Cidade                    1568
54      Will                           1558
55      Daniel Earwicker               1522
56      womp                           1490
57      mquander                       1488
58      casperOne                      1419
59      Ladislav Mrnka                 1409
60      Tomas Petricek                 1356
61      Femaref                        1346
62      Timwi                          1345
63      Ed S.                          1343
64      Joe                            1338
65      Ben Voigt                      1330
66      Cody Gray                      1313
67      Jon                            1296
68      Robert Harvey                  1286
69      Yuriy Faktorovich              1285
70      Daniel A. White                1248
71      Pavel Minaev                   1246
72      Jeff Yates                     1242
73      Aliostad                       1230
74      itowlson                       1215
74      Joey                           1215
76      James Curran                   1187
77      David B                        1181
78      Josh Einstein                  1178
79      Frederik Gheysels              1176
80      David Heffernan                1170
81      AnthonyWJones                  1164
82      astander                       1163
83      Gabe                           1154
84      BoltClock                      1152
85      Lucero                         1148
86      Richard                        1139
87      280Z28                         1098
88      Daniel Brückner                1097
89      Michael Stum                   1086
90      Lee                            1083
91      Tim Robinson                   1079
92      Remus Rusanu                   1075
93      Heinzi                         1062
94      Alex Aza                       1061
95      Brian                          1056
96      Craig Stuntz                   1052
97      Randolpho                      1050
98      MusiGenesis                    1048
99      John Feminella                 1040
100     FlySwat                        1039
101     M4N                            1027
102     Stephen Cleary                 1004
103     Øyvind Knobloch-Bråth          1002
104     Ahmad Mageed                    996
105     abatishchev                     992
106     Klaus Byskov Hoffmann           990
107     Chris Taylor                    984
108     jgauffin                        982
109     Davide Piras                    977
```

Comment: @donroby I'll try and fix it if you tell me which tag and for which user?

Comment: For me (userid=220834) the tag "wicket" didn't show up.  I'm the top answerer.  On rerun, I also notice that it marks me as 1 for wicket-tester, where I'm only second-to-top.  Might be an off-by-one.

Comment: And to further the suspicion, using userid=342852, he shows 1 for wicket and doesn't show for wicket-tester.  He's the top for wicket-tester and second (after moi) for wicket.

Comment: @donroby I wasn't the author of the original query. Rather than figure out why it was broken I simply rewrote from scratch. It now work with the user ids you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter I'm real late to the party and second query link (the list) is dead. Don't suppose you know where it is living these days?

Comment: @John I updated the link. It was easier to recreate the query than to find it.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Thanks appreciate it. Is the rank all time per tag, or is there a filter of some sort. The totals are smaller than I expected...

Comment: Is it possible there is a bug in there somewhere? An example, on Graphic Design site, color-theory has a top score of 3, while I have a single answer with a score of 8. Also common tags like adobe-photoshop show no results at all.

Comment: @john it's possible there's a bug. Can you post the url of the query you ran.

Comment: [graphicdesign.stackexchange.com](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) has a common tag 'adobe-photoshop'. Although I did discover per the answer above that this also gives the results I was after: [http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com//tags/adobe-photoshop/topusers](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com//tags/adobe-photoshop/topusers)

Comment: @John It seems that Beta sites don't show up in http://data.stackexchange.com/ Perhaps you should [upvote this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188465/148672)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter vote added. It is strange that some tags like color-theory or typography return partial results... Thanks for the help.

Comment: @John That's because you're querying the Stack Oveflow datadump. [tag:color-theory] and [tag:typography] are valid tags there. I'm sure if you tried it on Cooking it wouldn't be there. As a side note the query disappeared again. I don't know why.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter currently only 360 people have algorithm bronze badge and I'm one of them, so I must be 360'th person in worst case, but your query give me 501 !(and it is 501 for some time as I checked)

Comment: the second query doenst' seem to work anymore: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/124648/tag-fun

Comment: @dynamic. I fixed the link. Not sure why that happened

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter: thanks! Is there a way to show a list of all users ordered by reputation for a single tag? (maybe filtered by some location :)

Comment: @dynamic to get all users, Put 0 for user ID for all users.  If you want to add a filter for location you can fork the query and use the users.location field. Some people [just hard code the filters](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=italy) . There's also [the query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/48376?UserId=496223) I wrote for this [Meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107610/148672) that wasn't well received.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter: +1, but to filter for location, don't you need another join with the users table inside your query?

Comment: @dynamic Yeah you're right, I'd forgotton I used `[User Link]`to get the display name. Of course it's more complicated than just adding a join and where clause since you probably want how users rank within their location. I've modfied [the other query to take in a locaiton filter.](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/48376/regional-top-10-answerers-by-tag-top-40-tags-only?Location=Italy&UserId=0) If you wanted to you could remove the TOP 40 part of the query and/or add a tag filter

Comment: Shouldn't be location LIKE '%param%' ?

Comment: @dynamic You're welcome to change it by clicking the link "fork query" at the bottom.

Comment: Yes, I did some slight edit, now this query returns top users by a tag filterd by location http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/308043/regional-top-10-answerers-by-tag-top-40-tags-only?Location=italy&UserId=0

Comment: Awesome query, thank you! Do you think it can be modified to pull up top ranked users for a combination of tags? This could be useful if, for example, I am looking for top experts in both 'javascript' and 'excel'.

Comment: @July.Tech It sure can. See this [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112288/how-do-i-find-my-rank-for-a-specific-tag/112289?noredirect=1#comment830947_112289)

Comment: I must be slow, sorry. The query in the comment you pointed to pulls up top answerers by location for a single tag. Am I not reading it right? I am looking to rank users by points across all questions tagged with tag1 AND tag2 on them. Sorry if I am not making sense.

Comment: How to add Country as parameter to this query ? How to calculate the rank by country.

Answer (score 4):

For late-comers: You can approximate this by using the Developer Story feature that SO recently added. If you include tags in your profile and you rank high in that tag, your dev profile will include it. [Mine shows](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/321785) the tags I'm top 1%, 5%, and 10% in.

Comment: While not accurate, that's indeed a neat way.

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest you'd get is the Top Users page for the tag.

You'll always be the 21st user listed. (Unless you're actually in the top 20)