# Beta sites should be in the Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer, beta-sites

The Stack Exchange Data Explorer is a very nice and useful tool, but it has one very large drawback: Beta sites are not included at all.

Excluding beta sites probably made a lot of sense when the beta phase was supposed to last only 90 days and when updates to the Data Explorer were performed manually. With sites staying in the beta phase for years now this exclusion doesn't seem justified to me anymore.

*All* publicly launched sites should be included in the Data Explorer, there are more beta sites than launched sites in existence right now and excluding them does not really make any sense anymore.

Comment: Note that [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56300/when-will-stackexchange-sites-be-available-in-data-explorer) appears to indicate that it is [tag:status-completed]. That is incorrect: beta sites are not in the SEDE.

Comment: + 1 zillion. This would be great, I'd love to play around with it for my site. And from what you said it sounds like it should be a pretty easy change. *crosses fingers*

Comment: I'd also like to point out that the SEDE update process is now automated. I'm not sure how difficult the process was manually, but it doesn't seem like it would be that difficult to point that process at databases for beta sites.

Comment: Rather than all public sites, I think sites that are older than 4 months or so should be added. There should be some meaningful data to explore.

Comment: @AbdulRahman Just my two cents: the proposal is clear and adequately explained in the question; any answer I could post would be little more than "Yes! Everything you said!" So I think most people are letting their upvotes do the talking for them. Unless someone has a case *against* the proposal or more ideas to add positively to it, probably the only meaningful answer to the question can be from an SE employee commenting on its viability; and they have a lot of work to do so I would expect to wait more than 11 days for that :)

Comment: @WendiKidd: so this request will be accepted feature-request?

Comment: @WendiKidd You are right...unfortunately.  Instead of identifying *what* problems exist, and letting people give different answers as to *how* the problem can be solved (and letting there be separate votes on questions and answers), questions posing and question voting on Meta is a crude tool because of too many cases of questions including their own answers...and then you get question voting where votes of "I think this is/isn't a problem." are indistinguishable from votes of "I like/dislike this particular proposal for addressing it."  I wonder how difficult this would be to change...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Sites in **public** beta will now appear in the data explorer, refreshed weekly like everything else.

Comment: Hallelujah!! ...turns out 6-8 weeks was *somewhat* accurate :)

Comment: Allow me to translate this to common parlance: "They all lived happily ever after!"

Answer (score 43):

Yes, this!

I don't know why I didn't think of it before. The single most significant thing about a site getting out of beta to me is access to the DE. I've always taken the answer that "beta sites aren't in the DE" as just the way it had to be, but come to think of it there doesn't seem to be a good reason for this any more.

1. It should take almost no time on the part of developers.
2. Since beta sites are relatively small in the scheme of things, it shouldn't take up many resources.
3. The beta phase is exactly when it would be most useful to find certain kinds of trends that only the DE will reveal.
4. Early beta users are the most likely to be enthusiastic about examining "their baby".
5. Data dumps are available for *failed* betas and *successful* betas. Why not active ones?
6. Unicorns.

Pretty please?

Answer (score 32):

This is [in the works](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1631090#1631090), so hopefully beta sites will have their data become available in SEDE within the next few weeks (as of this edit), now that Data Explorer has been [moved back to proper hardware](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/413752186922086400).

Comment: That's **awesome** news!!

Comment: 6 to 8 weeks™, the most bittersweet promise in all of Stack Exchange. Keeping my fingers crossed!

Comment: @jmac Sooner than that, it's mostly just waiting on new hardware to finish coming in. :)

Answer (score 26):

To elaborate on @Caleb's post, here are two specific examples of how the lack of Data Explorer support for beta sites hurts us:

- We would like to [compare performance against graduated sites](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1015/9357)
- We would like to [target specific kinds of posts](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1014/9357) for action

Please??

Comment: Check out Tim Stone's answer!!