# Can I get historical info from the API?

Tags: support, api

I'm making a [statistics display](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/464/what-do-our-historical-statistics-look-like) for one of the beta sites I'm active on. Unfortunately, the API's `/info` method only gives me the *current* data. I'm currently calling the method every so often and storing the response in a SQL db, but it would be nice to have some older data preloaded into the system.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I would say Data Explorer, but DE doesn't contain beta site information.

Comment: [... yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207963/163863) (@hichris123).

Comment: @Matt Thanks for linking it. Was going to mention it, but didn't want to search for the post.

Comment: @hichris123 Does DE contain historical info at all?

Comment: @UndotheSnowman: No. The closest you probably have is the CC data dump on Clear Bits, which provides historical snapshots of the data; http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump