# Easy way to access beta sites

Tags: support, beta-sites, communities-list

The sites I participat(ed) in are linked on the top right in "your communities" for easy switching between them. However the beta sites don't seem to be there (like [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com)). Is there any UI element I miss to make it appear there (or elsewhere) without typing in that URL directly?

This is only somewhat related to [this ancient question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188465/beta-sites-should-be-in-the-data-explorer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "... the beta sites don't seem to be there (like Open Source). Is there any UI element I miss to make it appear there (or elsewhere) without typing in that URL directly?".

Yes.

- Click on the "Hamburger" (upper right corner)
- On the "Your Communities" line choose "edit"
- Type a few letters of the site's name
- Select the site and "Add" it
- Click "Save" when you've added all your choices

Here is both "Open Source" and the "Operations Research" new beta site.

[image: Pull down menu]

The site you offered as an example is listed in the chooser. In a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340264/easy-way-to-access-beta-sites#comment1137115_340265) you asked to have it listed without searching, by *adding* it to your list it will always be easily available.

Comment: Interesting :) I missed the edit button... and yes, I think, I need to change the accepted answer as I cannot accept both

Comment: The owner of the question chooses which answer to accept, if you think other answers are more helpful you can pick them even if they don't answer your question.

Answer (score 8):

To quickly find a community you're a member of (unless like me you've joined all 174 of them), navigate to the Accounts tab of your network profile with this link: 
https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=accounts

[image]

Beta sites are listed there just like the others. If you don't know the link, you can get there via your profile page on a site, and then the link 'Network Profile', then the tab 'accounts'. Or via the top bar on https://stackexchange.com/ when you click your avatar.

---

To find *all* Stack Exchange communities, please scroll down a bit, you'll find a section called

> MORE STACK EXCHANGE COMMUNITIES

with a search bar:

[image]

Just type words that appear in the site name or description:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I find them that way. But I find every community that way, and then typing the URL and using browser's memory is faster.
My concern is that the communities I am already part of, should be visible without searching all dozens of communities, but above that general list in "my communities"

Comment: @planetmaker gotcha, then your best option is your network profile. See my updated answer.

Comment: ...and I learnt there is a required delay before I can accept an answer. tyvm.