# Have weekly and monthly leagues only with points from question of that week / month

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation-leagues

I hope this hasn't been asked, I checked the site and didn't find anything. I just was wondering if it was ever considered to create weekly /monthly /yearly leagues with reputation calculated only from questions opened in that week / month / year.

I know it's perfectly possible to get to the top even if you joined the site later (I was number 63 in July 2011 and I started contributing in May 2011), but I think it would be more "encouraging" for new users to be able to compete with others without older users having the "advantage" of reputation gained from old posts.

Comment: But we _want_ to encourage people to write answers that continue to collect upvotes a long time after the question has left the front page. Because that means they're useful to more people than just the original askers. That's a good thing. So if it gives people an advantage in the rep leagues, I'd say it's well deserved.

Comment: @hammar yes of course i'm not saying that you shouldn't continue to collect upvotes, you could have the normal leagues and the leagues withouth the rep from old posts. In my mind this is just a way to "ease" new user that are a little bit "frightened" when entering the site

Comment: [I tried a different request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107610/create-regional-user-leagues-and-tag-toppers) for the same reasons as you did. It went over about as well.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Overflow is not designed around competing for reputation. It's designed around helping people who need help. The reputation system is designed to allow better answers to appear higher up.

As far as competing goes, if that's what floats your boat, high rep users achieve reputation cap most days. And so differentiation in reputation leagues comes down to how many answers get accepted. And you only score points that way from current activity. Stated more simply, any given answer can be accepted once and once only.

So whilst you might think that leaders of the reputation leagues are in that position due mainly to reputation gained from historical answers, that is most definitely not the case. I you look more closely at the sharp end of the reputation leagues you will see a number of users who only became active quite recently.

Comment: It was just an idea, i stated in my question that it is possible to top the leagues even if you start today. I don't agree with the `Stack Overflow is not designed around competing for reputation ` part, because if that was the case, why have weekly / monthly / yearly leagues?

Comment: (and i read a lot of comments from new user that "old users" are "impossible to compete with" and so i made this proposal

Comment: But the evidence does not support that. There are lots of recently active users near the top of the leagues. Sure it takes a bit of learning to work out how to score highly, but I guess most people complaining about it being too hard to compete with more experienced users are just suffering from sour grapes. My advice is keep trying and you will get better.

Comment: I know, i was number 63 in July and i know that if i try harder i can do even better, it was a general question since i read that a lot of new user are a little discouraged when competing, i was just wondering if this could make life easier for newcomers. :)

Comment: I don't agree with "the Stack Overflow is not designed around competing for reputation part", either